# Distributing evenly the Cell value of column A to B C D

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to Excel VBA so please be good to me :)

My problem is I want to copy values of Column A until the last cell with value and paste it to B C D respectively

Example

Column A has 3 Rows with values Tim,john,Mer respectively

I want to paste it to Columns B2 C2 D2 respectively too

Problem: Column A has a dynamic number of row so I want it to copy until the last notempty cell. but when column A is more than 3 (number of columns to paste) it will loop and paste it to B3 then C3 then D3 and so on until all non empty cell is distributed evenly to the 3 columns(B,C, and D)

Hope this problem is clear

Comment: Try recording a macro and see what code you get.

Comment: try to write two nested loops. One will loop A1 to A100 and inner will switch B,C,D and write the values

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim x As Long, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To 100 Step 3
    x = x + 1
    Range("A" & i & ":A" & i + 2).Copy
    Range("B" & x).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , , True
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make use of the `TRANSPOSE` function?

```
Sub TransposeToColumns()

    Dim lLastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Get the last row (same as going to end of sheet and pressing Ctrl+Up).
        lLastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If lLastRow > 3 Then
            'Cells(1,2) is row 1, column 2.
            With .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, lLastRow + 1))
                'R1C1 style of referencing - absolute reference to A1 is R1C1 (row 1 column 1).
                .FormulaArray = "=TRANSPOSE(R1C1:R" & lLastRow & "C1)"
                'Replace formula with values.
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Just realised - this will error out if you try and do it with more than 16383 rows (i.e. the number of columns -1).  But it will do all columns in 0.040469668631069 seconds. :)